WIndows powershel ps1 file extension not being recongized
I am trying to run a powershell script on windows. I wrote the script in notepad and saved it .ps1. However, the property of the file remains txt. I dont know what I am doing wrong.
I tried to run the file even though it is a txt extension, and it does not work from powershell.

If filename is something like name.ps1.txt then this is still seen as a txt and will open with default application for txt extension.  You would have to rename the file and remove the .txt part.  In PowerShell from the same folder you can do Rename-Item -Path 'name.ps1.txt' -NewName 'name.ps1'

When you save your file using notepad, make sure you change the "Save as ..." option to All files to avoid having the .txt extension automatically added

I'm afraid you'll need to review basics first.

From File Explorer, navigate to View tab and select the check box of 'File name extensions'. After enabling this option, you will be able to see the file extensions.
Then select your PowerShell file, rename and remove the .txt extension.
I attached screenshot for your reference:

